# Usare correttamente 'fatti curare'

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In Italia sento spesso dire «Fatti curare».

È questa un'espressione alternativa di «abbi cura di te»?

Answer (score 13):

No. In questo caso, *curare* si riferisce alla salute mentale: si dubita della sanità mentale, e quindi della capacità di fare ragionamenti corretti, dell'interlocutore. Non è un dubbio "reale"; viene usato solamente per insultare l'interlocutore e la sua tesi.

L'espressione può essere usata anche in senso letterale, chiaramente in contesti appropriati, ma per evitare incompresioni userei qualcosa di meno ambiguo e potenzialmente offensivo.

Non è possibile che sia un'espressione alternativa ad *abbi cura di te*, perché in italiano "farsi curare" significa solamente *ricevere cure mediche*.

Answer (score 5):

No. "Fatti curare" è generalmente usato in senso offensivo, nel senso che si crede che l'interlocutore abbia problemi mentali.